# Fetching values from MySQL table for objects with different relationships: several queries or one?

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, fetch

I'm building a kind of a forum, so I need to display posts. Each post has comments and tags assigned to it, and each post is assigned to a user; also, each comment is assigned to a user. So what I need to fetch is: a post, it's comments and their authors' usernames, it's tags and the user who the post is assigned to. Displayed post looks something like this:

```
post_title (submit_time)
tag1, tag2, tag3
user_name

    comment_text
    user_name

    comment_text
    user_name

    etc.
```

The problem is that relationships between posts, users, comments and tags are all different. Posts to users have an N:1 relationship (multiple posts for one user), posts to comments have a 1:N relationship (multiple comments for one post), posts to tags have m:n relationship (any number of tags for any number of posts).

I have devised a complex query with a lot of LEFT JOINs that allows me to fetch all data for each object, but it has a lot of duplicating rows (for example, if there are 5 comments, data about the post author will be fetched 5 times; it gets even worse with tags). This doesn't seem very rational. Also, it still makes me do another query for each comment to find it's author's user_name.

I'm a bit of a newbie with MySQL, so I really have no idea how such problem should be tackled.

The question is: what is the best way to fetch such data? Should I make one large query, or a lot of small ones (fetch comments and tags with distinct queries for each post)?

Please comment if my situation is unclear: I will do my best to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it IS ok to use multiple queries to fetch data. In your case, you CAN use a monolithic big query to fetch a user's data, all their posts, and all the comments, but as you say - there's a lot of repeated data. If you end up throwing away most of a query's results because it's repeated data, then it's a very good candidate for splitting up:

```
1 query to fetch the user info
1 query to fetch the user's posts
1 query to fetch the posts' comments
```

The end result being that you're fetching the user's info only once. Assuming a particular user has 20 posts with around 50 comments, your monolithic single query would fetch 20x50 = 1000 copies of the user details, and 50 copies of the post details, causing you to throw away 999 + 30 = 1029 records' worth of user/post data.

By comparison, at the cost of doing 3 queries, you're fetching only 1+20+50 = 71 rows of data, none of which is redundant.

Comment: But isn't making lots of queries very harmful for performance, especially if there are many users doing that simultaneously?

Comment: Fetching a ton of data you're just going to throw away is harmful too, causing the DB server to have to spit out a lot of extra data that's not wanted/needed. You'd have to benchmark your particular system to figure out what the point is where it's more efficient to use multiple smaller queries instead of the big single one. Consider the overhead of having to send those extra 1029 records' worth of data over the wire - if you're connecting via tcp, that's a LOT of extra data packets + tcp overhead.